# get list of string with matcher in java/android

Tags: java, android, string, list, matcher

I have a string like

```
number +919999999990  time at:07:42:45 on 10.04.2014, number
+919999999991 time at:08:42:45 on 11.05.2014,  number +919999999992 time at:075:42:45 on 05.03.2014 , number +9199999999913 ,time at:27:40:45 on 09.04.2015.
```

I have to retrieve all phone-numbers , date and time .
I am planning to use pattern and matcher.

My code is

```
String extra1="number +919999999990  time at:07:42:45 on 10.04.2014, number +919999999991 time at:08:42:45 on 11.05.2014, number +919999999992 time at:075:42:45 on 05.03.2014 , number +9199999999913 ,time at:27:40:45 on 09.04.2015.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+\\d{12}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(extra1);
System.out.println("matcher.groupCount() "+matcher.groupCount());
if (matcher.find()) {
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }   
} else {
     System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) it should print all the phone numbers.
But I am getting only the first phone number.

Can anyone suggest a solution...

Comment: In a console app, that prints all but the first number. (It doesn't print the first number because you're calling `find` twice before you print anything...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the ´if (matcher...)´statement wich will consume the first number, it works fine for me:

```
    String extra1 = "number +919999999990  time at:07:42:45 on 10.04.2014, number +919999999991 time at:08:42:45 on 11.05.2014, number +919999999992 time at:075:42:45 on 05.03.2014 , number +9199999999913 ,time at:27:40:45 on 09.04.2015.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+\\d{12}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(extra1);
    System.out.println("matcher.groupCount() " + matcher.groupCount());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

output:

```
matcher.groupCount() 0
+919999999990
+919999999991
+919999999992
+919999999991
```